# Fatal Exception: AsyncTask #3 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-asynctask

I'm trying to run my react native application on Android, the app works perfectly on iOS, but when I compiler it on android, the app crashes and give me the message: 
 `unfortunately, the app has stopped working`

my logcat:

```
 04-25 10:34:40.514 7810-7866/com.ferretotalapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
                                                                 Process: com.ferretotalapp, PID: 7810
                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions
                                                                     at com.airbnb.android.react.maps.AirMapManager.<init>(AirMapManager.java:52)
                                                                     at com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage.createViewManagers(MapsPackage.java:39)
                                                                     at com.facebook.react.XReactInstanceManagerImpl.createAllViewManagers(XReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:699)
                                                                     at com.facebook.react.CoreModulesPackage.createUIManager(CoreModulesPackage.java:206)
                                                                     at com.facebook.react.CoreModulesPackage.access$200(CoreModulesPackage.java:71)
                                                                     at com.facebook.react.CoreModulesPackage$8.get(CoreModulesPackage.java:145)
                                                                     at com.facebook.react.CoreModulesPackage$8.get(CoreModulesPackage.java:142)
                                                                     at com.facebook.react.LazyReactPackage.createNativeModules(LazyReactPackage.java:76)
                                                                     at com.facebook.react.XReactInstanceManagerImpl.processPackage(XReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:958)
                                                                     at com.facebook.react.XReactInstanceManagerImpl.createReactContext(XReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:863)
                                                                     at com.facebook.react.XReactInstanceManagerImpl.access$600(XReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:110)
                                                                     at com.facebook.react.XReactInstanceManagerImpl$ReactContextInitAsyncTask.doInBackground(XReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:214)
                                                                     at com.facebook.react.XReactInstanceManagerImpl$ReactContextInitAsyncTask.doInBackground(XReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:193)
                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
04-25 10:34:40.536 7810-7835/com.ferretotalapp W/unknown:InspectorPackagerConnection: Couldn't connect to packager, will silently retry<br> <br>
04-25 10:34:40.714 7810-7844/com.ferretotalapp E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xf3e145a0
```

Comment: The error is actually a bit deeper, `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the following lines in your build.gradle file located inside the "app" directory. The error is caused because ART is not able to locate Class file for GoogleMapOptions.

```
dependencies {
   ...
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'
   ...
}
```

Comment: @Marco Portillo Please upvote, if you accept the answer.